# How to dynamically share data between MyAppUITests and the MyApp target?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, ios9, ui-testing

Within `MyAppUITests` I can pass some parameters to MyApp in following way:

```
app.launchEnvironment = ["my_param": "value"]
app.launch()
```

This is visible for `MyApp` and I can read this:

```
if let value = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment["my_param"] {
   //do sth with value
}
```

But this is how I can set it up **BEFORE** I launch the app. For some reason, I need to change `"my_param"` on runtime **AFTER** I launch the app. Any suggestions? I would appreciate any help.

**Why do I need to do it for?**

I need `"my_param"` to be able to change within `MyAppUITests` after I launch the app. `"my_param"` needs to be visible for `MyApp` in whatever place within `MyApp`. `my_param` might be mock response for my network client or whatever I need for that time.

**NOTE:**

Similar functionality is between App and its extension. There is solution with `App Group` and shared `NSUserDefaults`. What is here? Do I have to save it on device to share sth to another target?

**UPDATE:**

`App Group` doesn't work here.

Comment: Please give a concrete example of what you're trying to do and if you already tried something. Now the question is not very clear.

Comment: I updated the question.